# Concurrent access to non-overlapping ranges of RTL_BITMAP

Tags: multithreading, driver, thread-synchronization, windows-kernel

I have a bitmap in my device driver, implemented using a Windows [RTL_BITMAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/eprocess) object and manipulated using the RtlXxx bitmap routines ([RtlSetBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlsetbits), [RtlCheckBit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlcheckbit), etc), that is shared between multiple threads.

Each thread is restricted to reading/writing only a certain range of bits in the bitmap. The range accessed by each thread is non-overlapping with the range accessed by every other thread, i.e., no two threads are interested in any of the same bits.

e.g.,

```
001110100101011110011101010101010100001111...10010101101001
<--thread A--><--thread B--><--thread C-->...<--thread Z-->
```

There are no guarantees as to the number of bits in each thread's range, and therefore no guarantees about memory alignment. For example, thread A might be assigned bits [0, 13], and thread B assigned bits [14, 27]. This means that, in general, the bits used by one thread may be held in memory in the same byte as the bits used by another thread.

**Is it safe to manipulate the bitmap from multiple threads simultaneously e.g., without synchronization, so long as the bits being accessed by each thread are unique to that thread?**

My concern is that operations involving bits that share the same word in memory could produce inconsistent results. For example, the "set bit" operation could be implemented something like:

1. load register with word containing bit from memory
2. `OR` the appropriate bit into the register
3. store the register back to memory

If this were not an atomic operation, then if two threads attempt to set two different bits that happen to be stored in the same shared word, one of the bits could be "lost".

Disassembling the RtlSetBit routine in ntoskrnl, it seems that bit sets are performed using `bts`:

```
fffff802`ac6620dc 488b4108        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+8]
fffff802`ac6620e0 0fab10          bts     dword ptr [rax],edx
fffff802`ac6620e3 c3              ret
```

This would *seem* to be atomic enough, but it doesn't seem enough to rely on in general.

Comment: I'm not very much into kernel development, but the first thing that I saw is that `bts` is performing its operation on a DWORD (that's 32 bits which can be used simultaneously by multiple threads) and the instruction is **not** using a `LOCK` prefix. Basically the API is not thread safe. I would really use a synchronization  primitive (e.g. a spin lock) before calling the API .

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you @Neitsa. Especially given the Intel reference for BTS specifically says "This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically." i.e., it's not atomic unless LOCK is specified. And in any case, the higher-level routine (RtlSetBit) makes no guarantee one way or another, and it could be different on different architectures.